# Python script cannot find file only sometimes

Tags: python, ioerror

I am running a Python script multiple times and the only thing that changes each time is the name of my run.

Approximately 50% of the time, the runs fail and I get the error output:

`IOError: Cannot find file filename.txt`

But the file is certainly in that location when I check. And the same file is also used by all the other runs that succeed.

So I'm just trying to understand what if there is anything that could be producing this error only sometimes.

I don't know if it's relevant but I am submitting the jobs via Slurm on a remote machine.

Comment: does the file exist before you start the jobs or does it get created on the fly? Do you have many parallel steps? If you have parallel processes and one of them is creating the file, it can sometimes happen that some other process is faster than the one that writes the file. And when it try to read it, it is not written yet. If this is the case, you need to wait on writing operation with some lock or mutex.

Comment: Try using the complete file path. Is the Python process always running in the same path as the file?

Comment: Often searching with the Exception/error text will provide enough SO Q&A's to give you an idea of what might be happening.

Comment: @wwii I do actually have the entire path in the code and it is the same for all runs.

Comment: @berkay-berabi the file that it cannot find does actually exist before the run and is not modified or anything. But I do think that something like this must be happening.

Comment: You may create a simple test case of looking up the same file, run it in parallel with your problematic script, and monitor changes in outcome. Try to use assertion somewhere in the code to catch a condition equivalent to the same scenario (e.g., the directory being empty)